# Flutter warning line never hidden

Tags: flutter

I am still a beginner on Flutter, I don't understand why the warning lines still visible, there is no code yet, even when I tried to fill this screen, that's lines still visible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPH6L.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hover mouse cursor on code & it will let you know what is causing the line to appear. Please share that message here.
Use snake_case for naming source files, like:
main_screen.dart, splash_screen.dart, or home.dart.
Keep caps lower and use underscores to separate words.

Comment: # Name source files using `lowercase_with_underscores`.

The messages are also weird, I am using (EmailPassScreen) as a name for this class, and when named it as (email_pass_screen) , I got these messages 

1- Name source files using `lowercase_with_underscores`.
2- Name types using UpperCamelCase.

Comment: I got it. Can you please share the name of the file containing this code?

Comment: In Flutter, the naming convention for file names is in snake_case. File names should be like main_screen.dart, home.dart, or splash_screen.dart. Keep caps low and use underscores to separate words.

Comment: Oh What the heck, it's not like JAVA or Kotlin , it was solved , thank you Rashid

Comment: No worries! Enjoy Fluttering!✨